# how to make a web address available in LAN?

Tags: dns, resolution, hostname, local

I have a question regarding how or what's the technology behind the scene to make a hostname available in LAN?

For example, one can go to http://tplinkeap.net to directly configure your local router (or switch), and that tplinkeap.net address "automagically" got resolved to a local IP address (192.168.1.155 for example)

I understand there's mDNS/NetBIOS/Bonjore, but seems like it only makes a hostname accessible by [hostname].local format. However, as far as I understand, doesn't a .net address always require a public DNS record?
And I suppose the tp-link's solution works both on Windows and Non-Windows servers.

Someone knows how do these network device companies make this available please help reveal the mystery. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a similar question, how does the printer register itself by names in local network? My local router/switch definitely doesn't have a DNS service, so I wonder what technology does that.

Answer (score 0):

They could  use a public DNS record and point it to a private IP address, which would be the TP-Link device's default IP but, as that could vary by device or model, and would depend on someone having existing internet connectivity (which would possibly defeat the point of needing a TP-Link device - such as a router) it is most likely that they are using host-header redirection to grab the portion of your request that says what site you tried visiting and then directing your traffic to the web daemon built into the TP-Link device, the IP of which is already known as you have either obtained an IP by DHCP or statically assigned one (including a gateway IP) per the instructions included with your device.

Another possibility is that the device is acting as a transparent proxy (similar to what could be done with Squid) to hijack traffic destined for tplinkeap.net and direct it to an internal httpd on the device.

Also, no, .net does not always require a public DNS record. If you host your own DNS services, you could create a zone of a .net-based domain and override any/all entries at will to direct the traffic elsewhere. The same would be true with modifications to your local "hosts" file.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this and tried: nslookup tplinkeap.net  nothing shows up. also tried wget/curl tplinkeap.net, still nothing. You can try it too. Also, if using public DNS record, a working internet must be required. This is not the case for TP-LINK device either. You can access the web console even there's no internet.

Comment: Correct. Which is why I said they aren't doing that in this case. They're grabbing your request's header, extracting the portion that says tplinkeap.net, and directing it inward to the httpd (daemon) running on the device.

Comment: Interesting.. How is that done? Who are "they"? If there's no internet, how does my router/switch know tplinkeap.net is the local address 1921.168.1.155?

Comment: @Bob "They" are TP-Link.  You don't necessarily need internet access for that. All you'd potentially need is to send traffic to their gateway and it does the rest.  The other option is that they're running a transparent proxy that is set to capture all traffic using port 80, and to direct it that way.  I'll try to find a document to explain how host-header redirection works.

Comment: As promised, here is a document from the IETF about host headers: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4

Comment: Also, here is an answer given on the subject, on Stack Overflow, which explains how the redirection part works a little bit. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43156094

Comment: thank you very much, that's very helpful. Sorry one thing I didn't clarify, my router is a Cisco one, the TP-Link device is a ceiling mount wireless AP (AC1750). That's why I am puzzled, cuz my request packet is sent over to the Cisco device, and somehow it knows how to direct to the correct AP. (i.e. when I run, nslookup tplinkeap.net, it gives me 192.168.1.155, which is not part of the http protocol)

Comment: Well, now that you've clarified a little more, what I previously said is negated. Your initial description in no way, shape, or form alludes to there being a Cisco device in the picture and you even worded it in such a way as to imply your TP-Link device is a router/switch.

Comment: I dug a little bit and found that the address you use for configuration is tplinkap.net not tplinkeap.net. tplinkap.net IS publicly resolvable, and it looks like it knows if you're connected to your network through a router or through a TP-Link device. So, it's possible that my previous answers are still valid but I would need to know exactly what the instructions say to do to configure it from scratch.

Comment: Yea sorry that's my fault. Thank you so much for detailing the answers and for your patient. The detail of the AP setup is here: [https://www.tp-link.com/en/configuration-guides/quick_start_guide_standalone_eap/?configurationId=18701] (tp-link eap manual) where indicates "http://tplinkeap.net"

Comment: @Bob Thanks. So, now that I see what their instructions are, they have you verify that you're pulling a DNS server via DHCP and then visiting the website (which was what you said - you were correct).  That being the case, they are very likely (probably a certainty) using either of the methods I stated already.  Because you are connecting to the SSID the device is broadcasting, your Cisco device is out of the picture for the setup.  ALL traffic is being run through the WAP, where they can direct traffic as they need to for the setup process.

Comment: hmm that's possible and is very interesting. I don't have the device with me right now (it's an office device), but I can definitely try querying tplinkeap.net by wifi and ethernet to see the differences. Thanks again for digging the mystery with me =) Learnt couple of things along the way.

Comment: @Bob Sure. Let me know if you find anything else you want me to try and explain.

Comment: Hi, as what you indicated, I can only access to http://tplinkeap.net by connecting to WiFi. I couldn't connect to http://tplinkeap.net by using wired ethernet. So it must be TP-Link AP itself resolving the hostname. Thanks a lot for your help, mystery solved.

Comment: @Bob No problem.  Happy to help.  Please mark my answer and upvote it, if you feel it was adequate. Thanks.